# Как растянуть кнопки по всему LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, вёрстка, xml

Имеется горизонтальный LinearLayout, в нем 3 кнопки. Как мне сделать так, чтобы они занимали все место в layout'e, расстягивались сами, имели одинаковый размер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

КОД разметки:

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:onClick="captureImage"
                        android:text="Снимок"

                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnGallery"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:text="Галерея"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Калибровать"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:onClick="startCalibration"/>
```

Comment: Всем трём задать `android:layout_weight="1"` и ширину в `0dp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я считаю, что нужно:

1. Всем кнопкам назначить ширину 0dp;
2. Всем кнопкам назначить равный вес.

   ```
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:onClick="captureImage"
                   android:text="Снимок"

                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:textSize="12sp" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/btnGallery"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:text="Галерея"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:textSize="12sp" />

               <Button
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:textAllCaps="false"
                   android:text="Калибровать"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:textSize="12sp"
                   android:onClick="startCalibration" />
   ```