# Создание списка

Tags: android

Всем привет! Посоветуйте пожалуйста как можно создать такой список как на скринах. Пробовал на `ListView`, `TableLayot`, `LinearLayout`, `ExpandableListview`.
Проблема что не могу растянуть на весь экран.Первые 2 скрина это скрин работающей програмы из интернета это то к чему стремлюсь.[image: скрин1]
[image: скрин 2 где список со скролом уже и затенен]

```
 //Это код в фрагменте который показывет представление дневника







    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@color/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </RelativeLayout>




//Это xml кторый вызываеться для заполнение листа

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/vrec"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/linnn"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                android:text="@string/pn"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/month"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                android:text="month"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spisok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                android:text="Spisok del:"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/slash"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pisly"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/play"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar123"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_progress_bar" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/addtask15050"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dayList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lin"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: И вот как выходит]

И вот так на телефоне та выходит. Если маленькое количество пикселей на дюйм то список кидает в скрол а не масштабирует элемент под экран. Если делать через LinearLayout и  android:layout_weight="" то список при открытии просто сжимает  без скролла

Comment: Сама кастомизация не проблема, именно механизм начального списка, а то на одном телефонее   список за большой, и уже в скроле а на другом под списком  пустота, спасибо всем!

Comment: приведите код разметки, как вы у вас выглядит xml?

Comment: Хммм... Может, `layout_height="match_parent"`? [Ответ на похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011966/312975) вам может пригодиться, если необходимо оставить неизменной верхнюю панель, а список растянуть